# Controlling Android OS using a method different from finger touch

Tags: android, input, touch, android-service

I want to build a new input method for Android devices. By input method, I don't mean the input method for text, but the input method for the entire system. For example, the touch method is used to open and close different apps, also it can be used to change the device settings. So, this is what I want to do, I want to control the entire system using a method different from touch method.

I've searched a lot, all I found are input methods for text. For example, by using `InputMethodService`. I've found some `SDKs`, but they are commercial, I have no idea how they were built.

EDIT: To clarify more, here is an example. Some android devices can be entirely controlled without using touch method. The user may be able to control the entire device (not only inputting text) using their hands or eyes gestures. For example, There is a commercially available sdk for this purpose which is provided by Eye Tribe Tracker (check their website, https://theeyetribe.com/). Their sdk can be used to control the entire device, for example opening and closing apps, browsing the web, etc. All of these tasks can be done using eye gestures, no need for touching. So, this is what I want to do, I want to build an input method algorithm that can control android devices.

Can any one please tell me how to do this? I need a clear resource that explains the process with respect to android devices.

Thank You.

Comment: Not clear..!! Add any example..!!

Comment: Thanks, I will update the question.

Comment: @AndiGeeky, I updated the question, please check it. Thank You.

Comment: Before you can work on the new input method, the first step is to identify which hardware component or sensor will be used for the input data. In your example of Eye Ball Tracker, there is a sensor that needs to be installed on the system. Similarly, you will need to find a new sensor or use an existing sensor on the Android device for feeding the input data into this system.

Comment: @kmaini, thank you for your comment. I understand that I need to control some hardware in the device in order to receive the input from the user, but how can I let the applications know that if touch is not used then they must take their input from the output of that hardware? Is it like building an interface between applications and input hardware (like camera, or touch screen)? Is there a way to build such an interface in Android? Thank you.